# delegate method throws runtime "unrecognized selector" error when switching back from one UIViewController to the main View Controller

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, interface-builder

Ok, I've spend like half day on this and it's killing me.

So I've got 3 view controllers transitioning from one another, something like this:

I call the UploadDecisionViewController after destroying the previous View Controller:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
[self performSelector:@selector(showUDModalView) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];
```

In my showUDModalView method:

```
- (void)showUDModalView
{
    UploadDecisionViewController *udcontroller = [[UploadDecisionViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"UploadDecisionViewController" bundle:nil];
    udcontroller.delegate = self;

    [self presentModalViewController:udcontroller animated:YES];
    [udcontroller release];

}
```

The UploadDecisionViewController shows up no problem. The UploadDecisionViewController has a button, which when clicked I want it to transition to the FileUploadViewController. I setup a UploadDecisionDelegate, threw a method in there to handle the button clicking:

Inside UploadDecisionDelegate protocol (UploadDecisionViewController.h):

```
@protocol UploadDecisionDelegate

//let UOnliveViewController know that a button was selected
- (void)UploadDecisionViewController:(UploadDecisionViewController *)controller madeChoice:(NSString *)whichDirection;
@end
```

Then inside my IBAction method when the button is clicked, I have this:

```
- (IBAction)decisionSelected:(id)sender
{

    [delegate UploadDecisionViewController:self madeChoice:@"upload"];//crashing at this line

}
```

When I run this, at this line above it is throwing a runtime exception:

```
2010-06-09 12:48:59.561 UOnlive[4735:207] *** -[UIView UploadDecisionViewController:madeChoice:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3b65420
2010-06-09 12:48:59.562 UOnlive[4735:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[UIView UploadDecisionViewController:madeChoice:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3b65420'
2010-06-09 12:48:59.563 UOnlive[4735:207] Stack: (
    33502299,
    2495698185,
    33884219,
    33453686,
    33306306,
    20618,
    2982917,
    3390286,
    3399023,
    3394235,
    3087839,
    2996168,
    3022945,
    40156505,
    33287040,
    33283144,
    40150549,
    40150746,
    3026863,
    11700,
    11554
)
```

Let me throw in the delegate method implemented also:

```
- (void)UploadDecisionViewController:(UploadDecisionViewController *)controller madeChoice:(NSString *)whichDirection
{
    NSLog(@"it got to here 245");
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    if (yesOrNo) {
        //open up the FileUploadViewController and proceed to upload
        [self performSelector:@selector(showFUModalView) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];

    }
}
```

Can someone tell me what the heck is going on? Thanks a bunch for the help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says that you are trying to call the `UploadDecisionViewController` method on `UIView`.

My bet is that you set some view to the delegate instead of view controller.

Where the `showUDModalView` method is located?
Maybe you set the delegate in some additional places?

Comment: Yup, that was my problem. Thanks for help :) I set the delegate to the view in the nibs... :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is to lengthy and I dont want to go through this but just an advice, you can c if your object can/cannot perform a selector with this kind of statement:

```
if([myObj respondsToSelector:@selector(myFunc)])
{
 //do something
}
else{
//do something else
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I was just trying to be comprehensive. In a nutshell, the error is thrown when in the method where the button is linked to call another viewcontroller, I want to throw the control back to the main view controller by calling the delegate function but it is erroring in that call. Hope that makes it clear.